# Is there a way to run a subroutine when a user clicks a link from an email?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My program currently sends out an email when a new "Contact" has been added to my application.  This email includes a link that has the ContactID and will link to a page (Contacts.aspx).  This Contacts.aspx has a Gridview with various contact records inside of it.  Whenever a specific record is selected, it provides more information on that contact through a subroutine called `LoadContact(int ContactID)`.  It provides more information by showing a panel with various asp.net controls such as labels and checkboxes. My question is this:

Is it possible to set it up so that when the user clicks the link in the email, it takes them directly to the Contacts.aspx page and loads more information on that specific contact automatically rather than them having to click a specific record with that contactid?

Comment: Generate your link with query string information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a parameter to the link

```
Contacts.aspx?myparameter=foo
```

and then in your Codebehind-File access this in the Page Load Event

```
Request.QueryString("myparameter")
```

With that information you can select specific Data in your Gridview